# How does the following equation work in python x=4**3**5**7.Can someone please explain the order in which this is executed?

Tags: python

I have come across an online quiz question where the above mentioned equation was asked.So,wanted to know how it is executed(The order) when we have multiple power operators(**).

Comment: Did you check the documentation on [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)? If so, what part of it can we help you understand better? Particular, from the sentence "Operators in the same box group left to right (except for exponentiation, which groups from right to left)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something you can figure out with just a little experimentation:

```
>>> 2**3**4
2417851639229258349412352
>>> (2**3)**4
4096
>>> 2**(3**4)
2417851639229258349412352
```

Since the expression result matches what you get for `2**(3**4)`, *that's* the way it's interpreted.

This is confirmed in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) which states:

> The following table summarizes the operator precedence in Python, from lowest precedence (least binding) to highest precedence (most binding). Operators in the same box have the same precedence. Unless the syntax is explicitly given, operators are binary. ***Operators in the same box group left to right (except for exponentiation, which groups from right to left).***